# Generating Function for Hypergeometric Polynomials

Tags: generating-functions, hypergeometric-function

Problem 4, Chapter 9 in "Special Functions and Their Applications" (N.N. Lebedev)is to show that

$$w(z,t)=(1-t)^{\beta -\gamma }
   (1-t+z t)^{-\beta }=\sum
   _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(\gamma)
   _n \, _2F_1(-n,\beta ;\gamma
   ;z) t^n}{n!}$$ $| t| <\min  \left\{1,\frac{1}{|
   z-1| }\right\}$

Following the usual argument, we can expand $w (z, t )$ on a Taylor series about $ t =0$. $w(z,t)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   c_n(z) t^n$ where
$$c_n(z)=\int \frac{w(z,t)}{2 \pi 
   i t^{n+1}} \, dt$$
where the integration is along any circle of sufficiently small radius enclosing the point $t =0$. Inserting the expression for $w (z,t)$, we see that the integrand is very similar to that appearing in the well known integral formula for the Hypergeometric function.
This later formula however is a definite integral over the real axis from 0 to 1.

Employing the theory of residues we have
$$n! c_n(z)=\underset{t\to
   0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial
   ^n\left((1-t)^{\beta -\gamma }
   (1-t (1-z))^{-\beta
   }\right)}{\partial t^n}$$

In the case of the classic orthogonal polynomials (Legendre, Laguerre etc.), one would appeal to the appropriate Rodrigues formula at this stage. I am unaware of such type formula for the Hypergeometric function. Proceeding to evaluate the *n*th derivative by Leibnitz's rule, we obtain

$$n! c_n(z)=(-1)^n \sum _{k=0}^n
   \binom{n}{k} (-\beta
   )^{(k)} (\beta -\gamma
   )^{(n-k)} (1-z)^k$$
where $x^{(k)}=(x (x-1)
   (x-2)\text{...}) (x-(k-1))$

Hence, we must show that
$$(\gamma )_n \, _2F_1(-n,\beta
   ;\gamma ;z)=(-1)^n \sum
   _{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}
   (-\beta )^{(k)} (\beta
   -\gamma )^{(n-k)} (1-z)^k$$

It can be shown that
$$\, _2F_1(-n,\beta ;\gamma
   ;z)=\sum _{k=0}^n
   \frac{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}
   (\beta )_k z^k}{(\gamma
   )_k}$$

How do we show that these two polynomials are identical ?
I tried a proof by induntion, but was not successful.